# How to compare two timestamp values based on date ignoring time in js or moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```
unixTimeStamp1 = 1532676600;
unixTimeStamp2 = 1532680500;
```

I have to compare the above two unix time stamp values and return true if both the dates are same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the `toDateString` of each date:

```js
const getDateStr = secs => {
  const d = new Date(secs * 1000);
  return d.toDateString();
};
const d1 = getDateStr(1532676600);
const d2 = getDateStr(1532680500);
console.log(d1);
console.log(d2);
console.log(d1 === d2);
```

Comment: const getDateStr = function() {
  const d = new Date();
  return d.toDateString();
};

it will give same result

Comment: No, if you use that method, the resulting `dateStr`s will all be identical

Comment: Thankyou! It was really helpful. I was unaware of `toDateString` method. Its cool and solved most of my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the full date value from that timestamp using `new Date().toDateString()`. Then compare it. Also it is a unix timestamp so you need to convert that to JavaScript timestamp first using `unixTimeStamp * 1000`

```js
var unixTimeStamp1 = 1532676600;
var unixTimeStamp2 = 1532680500;
function checkDate(unixTimeStamp1, unixTimeStamp2){
  var date1 = new Date(unixTimeStamp1 * 1000).toDateString();
  var date2 = new Date(unixTimeStamp2 * 1000).toDateString();
  return date1 === date2;
}
console.log(checkDate(unixTimeStamp1, unixTimeStamp2));

unixTimeStamp1 = 1532156518;
unixTimeStamp2 = 1533839400;
console.log(checkDate(unixTimeStamp1, unixTimeStamp2));
```

But if you just want to get the date for the day ignoring the year and month then you can use `getDate()`:

```js
var unixTimeStamp1 = 1532676600;
var unixTimeStamp2 = 1532680500;
function checkDate(unixTimeStamp1, unixTimeStamp2){
  var date1 = new Date(unixTimeStamp1 * 1000).getDate();
  var date2 = new Date(unixTimeStamp2 * 1000).getDate();
  return date1 === date2;
}
console.log(checkDate(unixTimeStamp1, unixTimeStamp2));

unixTimeStamp1 = 1532156518;
unixTimeStamp2 = 1533839400;
console.log(checkDate(unixTimeStamp1, unixTimeStamp2));
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `The getDate() method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time.`

Answer (score 1):

```
var unixTimeStamp1 = 1532676600;
var unixTimeStamp2 = 1532680500;

var date1 = new Date(unixTimeStamp1 * 1000);
var date2 = new Date(unixTimeStamp2 * 1000);

if ((date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear()) && 
  (date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth()) &&
  (date1.getDate() === date2.getDate())
) {
  console.log("same");
}
```